# Joomla Registration: User exists - E-mail exists

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

how can I force Joomla to show the Error Messages that a username or e-mail exists already in the Database while registrating...

When I try to register as a new user with an existing username or/and e-mail I'll be redirected to the completely filled out registration form without any error message or hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Joomla shows errors messages for things like this. Whether they are displayed or not is down to your template. If you go to the following file:

```
templates/TEMPLATE_NAME/index.php
```

search for the following line which defines where Joomla messages are shown

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

If you cannot find it, add it to where ever you like